# Accessing Payment service configuration from within JAVA code

Tags: java, payment, intershop

At our webshop, there is a need to retrieve some payment method configuration values. On the old ES6.4 based webshop, we used to retrieve payment service configuration values like this:

```
Iterator<? extends PaymentInstrumentInfo> piis = order.createPaymentInstrumentInfoIterator(); /* order.getPaymentMethod(); */
    PaymentInstrumentInfo pii = piis.next();
    final String isCreditCard = pii.getPaymentService().getConfiguration().getString("CreditCardPayment");
    String pmn = pii.getPaymentService().getID();
```

In IS7.9 it seems the method getPaymentService() on PaymentInstrumentInfo object is deprecated, but in javadoc there is no explanation of deprecation in comment, it is just marked as deprecated.

How should we retrieve payment method service configuration params in IS7.9?

Comment: Are you sure that com.intershop.beehive.bts.capi.payment.PaymentInstrumentInfo.getPaymentService() is marked as @deprecated? I can't see it in the source.

Comment: It seems like the entire com.intershop.beehive.bts.capi.payment.PaymentService class is marked as deprecated.

Comment: Can you maybe help us by providing more information on what you're trying to achieve? Are you trying to migrate an existing connector? Then the new payment API is your friend. Are you trying to rework business functionality? Then please stick to the BusinessObject API layer and not the low level CAPI persistence layer

Comment: @JohannesMetzner we are working on migrating ERP connector. We have to create the order on the ERP through SOAP WS. Our webshop provides multiple payment methods and order creation on the external ERP system depends on numerous payment method service configuration params. Thats why we need to fetch the service configuration and read its params during web service request generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ISH offers a `GetPaymentServiceConfigurationByID` pipelet which retrieves the `PaymentServiceConfiguration` based on the ID and Domain.

The ID and the Domain for the `PaymentServiceConfiguration` can be found in the following way:

```
String serviceConfigurationDomain = pii.getServiceConfigurationDomain();
String serviceConfigurationID = pii.getServiceConfigurationID();
```

Be aware that the `getServiceConfigurationDomain` method returns a `String` instead of a `Domain`. To fetch the actual domain from this String you could use the `GetDomainByName` pipelet.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot actually use the pipelet but I decompiled it and this does the trick:

final PaymentServiceConfiguration serviceConf = paymentServiceConfFactory.getByDomainAndID(domainMgr.getDomainByName(pii.getServiceConfigurationDomain()),
      pii.getServiceConfigurationID());